# Compare data from a week(or minute) ago using Django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm, django-queryset

I have some data as follows:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField
    user_ID = models.CharField
    index_a = models.CharField
    cnt_a = models.BigIntegerField
    cnt_b = models.BigIntegerField
```

I would like to get Result data as follows:

| date | user_ID | sum(n.cnt_a) | sum(p.cnt_a)-5m | sum(n.cnt_b) | sum(p.cnt_b)-5m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-08-01 13:00 | a10 | 7011 | **6625** | 9239 | 8766 |
| 2021-08-01 13:00 | a20 | 6968 | **6628** | 9238 | 8765 |
| 2021-08-01 13:00 | a30 | 6940 | **6646** | 9238 | 8766 |
| 2021-08-01 13:00 | a40 | 6974 | **6644** | 9238 | 8764 |
| 2021-08-01 12:55 | a10 | **6625** | 6621 | 8766 | 8692 |
| 2021-08-01 12:55 | a20 | **6628** | 6580 | 8765 | 8691 |
| 2021-08-01 12:55 | a30 | **6646** | 6596 | 8766 | 8693 |
| 2021-08-01 12:55 | a40 | **6644** | 6614 | 8764 | 8692 |

I tried SQL query as follows: and get the Result as above Table

I am trying to **use Django ORM** to perform the following query without using raw SQL. any idea how can do that?

Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT n.date, n.user_ID, sum(n.cnt_a), sum(p.C_AAA), sum(n.cnt_b), sum(p.C_BBB)
FROM myModel AS n
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.date, t1.user_ID, t1.index_a, t1.cnt_a as C_AAA , t1.cnt_b as C_BBB
    FROM myModel AS t1
) AS p
ON p.date = DATE_SUB(n.date, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) AND p.user_ID = n.user_ID AND p.index_a = n.index_b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [execute custom sql queries directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly).

With Django API you can use `select_related` to perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, or [filtered relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects)

Note: `QuerySet` is a datatype returned by the Django API, it's not a tool.